# Error404 while loading CSS in HTML script in Python

Tags: python, html, css, flask

See the attached code: I get a 404 and there is a link to my directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}"
  </head>
  <body>
```

do you know whats wrong? see the directory here:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Gia.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Gia.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move static folder to flask folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}` thus without the `css/`

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
<head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static//css/main.css"
  </head>
```

in Flask edit this line:

this : `app=Flask (__name__)`

to this : `app=Flask (__name__,static_url_path="/static")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, howver still getting a 404!

Comment: GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404. Should I link to full path?

Comment: your .css file path must be like this from the .py file : ```static/css/main.css``` . after the edit use ctrl+F5  to clear cache

Comment: Thank you Revisto, will give it a try and come back to you!

Comment: [Pic of files](https://www27.online-convert.com/dl/web7/download-file/808320fd-c14b-4847-bf77-c8c3aa298703/Selection_057.png)

Comment: [Pic Html and .py](https://www42.online-convert.com/dl/web7/download-file/1489d7e4-aefd-4ffb-a89b-9ce921857bb9/Selection_058.png)